# Teaching to or teaching for?

Tags: grammar

What's the right way to write:
I have been teaching the course "xx" *to* Mr. Doe's group
or
I have been teaching the course "xx" *for* Mr. Doe's group
?

Answer (score 0):

If you say to Mr Doe's group, it means you are teaching to the group that Mr Doe is a part of or is related to. In second case, it can be interpreted as you are a part of Mr Doe's group which is responsible for teaching to someone else.